# I'm unable to normalize my Product table as I have 4 different product types

Tags: database, database-design

So because I have 4 different product types (books, magazines, gifts, food) I can't just put all products in one "products" table without having a bunch of null values. So I decided to break each product up into their own tables but I know this is just wrong (https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/742/23126857873_438655b10f_b.jpg).

I also tried creating an EAV model for this (https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5734/23479108770_8ae693053a_b.jpg), but I got stuck as I'm not sure how to link the publishers and authors tables.

I know this question has been asked a lot but I don't understand ANY of the answer's I've seen. I think this is because I'm a very visual learner and this makes it hard to understand what's being talked about when not a lot of information is given.

Comment: Do not use the EAv model if you want your system to work well with lots of records. It is a pain to query and very slow.

Comment: Why do you keep editing your questions to "This post included personal information."?    Just delete the question(s).

Answer (score 2):

Your model is on the right track, except that the product name should be sufficient you don't need Gift name, book name etc. What you put in those tables is the information that is specific to the type of product that the other products don't need. The Product table contains all the common fields. I would use productid in the child tables rather than renaming it giftID, magazineID etc. It is easier to remember what things are celled when you are consistent in nameing them.

Now to be practical, you put as much as you can into the product table especially if you are going to do calculations. I prefer the child tables in this specific case to have what is mostly display information.  So product contains the product name, the cost, the type of product, the units the product is sold in etc. The stuff that generally is needed to calculate the cost of an order or to have a report of what was ordered.  There may be one or two fields that can contain nulls, but it simplifies the calculation type queries  so much it might be worth it.

The meat of the descriptive details though would go in the child table for the type of product. These would usually only be referenced when displaying the product in the shopping area and only one at a time, so you can use the product type to let you only join to the one child table you need for display. So while the order cares about the product number and name and cost calculations, it probably doesn't need to go line by line describing the book ISBN number or the megapixels in a camera. But the description page of the product does need those things.

This approach is not purely relational, although it mostly is, but it does group the information by the meanings of the data and how they will be used which will make the database easier to understand and query. I am a big fan of relational tables because database just work better when they hit at least the third normal form but sometimes you can go too far for practicality, so the meaning of the data and the way you are grouping to use the data (and not just for the user interface, but for later reporting as well) is almost always one of my  considerations in design.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! So I just want to double-check, does this look correct? https://c2.staticflickr.com/6/5795/23410422439_ba8fd60358_b.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Breaking each product type into its own table is fine - let the child tables use the same id as the parent Product table, and create views for the child tables that join with Product

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure what you mean exactly, can you be a bit more specific? I do intend to have each child table's ID (BookID, MagazineID, etc) use the same ID from ProductID in the product table, however is it correct to relate all child tables to the ProductID primary key in the Products table like I did?

Comment: Use productid instead and make it the PK as well as the FK in the child tables.

Comment: yes, that's correct. What you have is basically an object-oriented inheritance hierarchy mapped to relational tables; see http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html#MapEachClassToTable - plus what HLGEM said!

Comment: So basically I actually had it correct, only I need to change the child IDs all to ProductID (and make them both foreyn and primary keys), and fix the relationship notations (I just copied/pasted the lines from previous relationships) correct?

Comment: @Te4mUp: yes! Nice work! But see also HLGEM's comments about what fields should go in each table (I didn't pay attention to non-key properties in your diagram)

Answer (score 0):

Your case is a classic case of types and subtypes.  This is often called class/subclass in object modeling and generalization/specialization in ER modeling.  It's a well understood pattern.  There are known techniques for dealing with this pattern.

Visit the following tabs, and read the description under the info tab  (presented as "learn more").  Also look over the questions grouped under these tags.

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

If you want to rean in more depth use these buzzwords to search for articles on the web.

You've already discovered and discarded single table inheritance on your own.  Other answers have pointed you at shared primary key.  Class table inheritance involves a single table for generalized data as well as the four specialized tables.  Shared primary key is generally used in conjunction with class table inheritance.